# - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView too slow in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a problem where scrolling up/down and setting the contentoffset from within `scrollviewdidscroll` on a secondary `scrollview` causes a minor jittery behaviour... or more accurately a low frame rate.

I currently rely on `scrollViewDidScroll` to manage effects such as Parallax in my `UIScrollView`, these effects are applied by listening for `scrollViewDidScroll`, but the turn around time for each call of this method is (for some reason), too slow and causes enough of a delay for it to look kind of bad when scrolling.

Interestingly, `iOS 9`, runs fine.

I've tried alternative methods, such as turning off images or using `AsyncDisplayKit` but both have no effect on the number of times `scrollViewDidScroll` is fired.

It looks to me that I may need to rearchitect the way I create the parallax effect, but I'm hesitant to in case there is a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - use Xcode Instruments debug tool "Time Profiler" (Xcode menu Product->Profile, then select Time Profiler from instruments).

Don't forget to check there "Invert Call Tree" and "Hide System Libraries" checkmarks, and detect problem place in your code.

After that you can find some solution.

At least you can try to add additional check before setting `contentOffset` property for second scroll view:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat contentOffsetForSecondScrollView = 123.0; // Calculate second scroll view content offset
    // Add additional check, if content offset doesn't change
    if (self.secondScrollView.contentOffset.y != contentOffsetForSecondScrollView) {
        self.secondScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, contentOffsetForSecondScrollView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the profiling suggestion led me to a single line of code, related to rounded corners of a UIView... Weird that it works perfect in iOS9.0 I've since just created an imageview of the rounded corners instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the effects in the below method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

Comment: This just means the UI is not updated until the user has released their finger, it also means animation doesnt work.

Answer (score -2):

Please put below delegate method to improve and detect scroling

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

   //Your code here
}
```

Comment: This just means the UI is not updated until the user has released their finger, it also means animation doesnt work.